# How to read structs properly

Tags: c++, memory, struct, mmap

I hope someone can help me. I'm trying to read file that consists of some amount of structs from below:

```cpp
struct query {
    int key;
    char surname[16];
    char name[16];
    char patronymic[16];
    char subject[16];
    int grade;
}s;
```

I need to use `mmap()` to read some data from file, for example to print all structs with same subject and grade, or print a query that has specific key.

In any other case I would use `fopen()` and `fread()` to read file with my structs. Something like this:

```cpp
FILE *inputFile;
inputFile = fopen("database.dat", "rb");
    while(fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, inputFile) == 1) {
        printf("\nKey: %d", s.key);
        printf("\nName: %s", s.name);
        printf("\nSurname: %s", s.surname);
        printf("\nPatronymic: %s", s.patronymic);
        printf("\nSubject: %s", s.subject);
        printf("\nGrade: %d", s.grade);
    }
```

But I can't get my head around `mmap()` so I have a few questions:

1. **How do I initialize `mmap()` with my file in first place?** I imagine something like this but I'm not sure (let's say that I know how much structs in file, let it be `amount` and `fd` is my proprer file descriptor).

```cpp
mmap(NULL, amount*sizeof(s), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Also what type of variable I assign this to so I can work with it?

2. **How do I go through all the structs in mapped file and compare their fields?** Normally (with `fread()`) I would just do nested cycles. But I have no idea what to do in mapped case.
3. **Is it possible to `mmap()` file without knowing amount of structs?** In first question I assumed that I know file length (`amount*sizeof(s)`). Can I map file without knowing `amount`?

I'm sorry if my terminology sounds off, I'm not really good at English.

Comment: *"I imagine something like this"* - Then the next step is to try it out and see what happens. Also, please don't tag spam. C or C++?

Comment: Your  file is an array of structs, so what type do you think it should be?

Comment: `mmap` has a reference page that documents what all of its parameters are and explains how to use them. Did you read `mmap`'s documentation? If so, which part of `mmap`'s documentation, specifically, are you unclear about? If not, you should read it first, and ask questions if something in the documentation is unclear to you.

Comment: 1) I'm using C syntax, but I'm compiling with `g++` so C++ code is also acceptable.
2) Thanks for clarification, I didn't know about being array of stucts.

Comment: When you're using a C++ compiler, tag it C++. There are some things that you need to do different in C and C++, for instance casting. I removed the C tag.

Comment: Both tags would be a good idea if you had a hard requirement that it needs to compile in both languages, but I suspect that's not the case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmap() can treat a file as being on memory.
And you don't need to know the file size.
See the sample code below:

```
    fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    fstat(fd, &buf);
    t = (struct query *)mmap(NULL, buf.st_size, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    for(i = 0; i < buf.st_size/sizeof(struct query); i++){
        printf("\nKey: %d", t[i].key);
        printf("\nName: %s", t[i].name);
        printf("\nSurname: %s", t[i].surname);
        printf("\nPatronymic: %s", t[i].patronymic);
        printf("\nSubject: %s", t[i].subject);
        printf("\nGrade: %d", t[i].grade);
    }
    close(fd);
```

Comment: I didn't know that my file acts as array of structs. Thank you very much!